# C# Best performing approach to order search results

Tags: c#, .net, search, hashset

wondering if anyone can suggest an approach for best performance

I will have a search function where a number (n) of attributes can be built up into a search profile.

Entities in the system will meet some or all of of those attributes and to a greater or lesser degree(Score). I need to be able to display a list of those that do 
in the order of entities with most attributes met. Initially I had thought that I would just use HashSet<>.Intersect() until 
I had the Entities that were in all sets but obviously that leaves me unable to rank all the others (n-1 met, n-2 met etc.).

It also won't work if I am holding the score as well as that will make each object added to the HashSet<> different even if its the same entity - correct ?

So now I am thinking I will search for a list of Entities that meet each of the attributes resulting in a Dictionary of Entities for each attribute and then 
run a count for how many attributes each entity has met. Is there a better way/better object types? I am sure this is pretty standard coding for some. This will be a core function so performance is key.

Comment: Sorry, does the score represent how many of the attributes each entity matches or is there a score for how much each entity matches each attribute?

Comment: The score represents how much each entity matches the attribute.